# The number of ordered pairs $a,b$ of natural numbers satisfying $a^b + b^a = 100$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> The number of ordered pairs $a,b$ of natural numbers satisfying $a^b + b^a = 100$

No clue ... Just unable to proceed...

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are just a little large $a^b+b^a$ quickly gets too big, so you can just put some bounds on them and try all the possibilities.  Because of the symmetry you can consider only $a \le b$, then flip around any cases where $a \neq b$  For example, if $a=2$ what is the largest $b$ can be?

Comment: @RossMillikan aaa....$b$ can not be greater than $5$ I think

Comment: No, try it on your calculator.

Comment: The answers are such a small set that it shouldn't take more than ten minutes to just list them all. There's only $6$ powers of $2$ and squares to check.  $100-4,8,16,32,64 \overtext ?= 4,9,16,25,36$ gives only $2^6+6^2=100$. Then are fewer powers of $3$ and cubes to check. $100 - 3^3,3^4 \ne 3^2 4^3$ And any $a^b; a,b > 3$ are that $a^b  > 100$ so we are done.  $2^6 + 6^2=100$ is only solution.

Comment: Oh, and $1^{99} + 99^1$ of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that (6,2) and (2,6), (99,1) and (1,99) are the only solutions.

Indeed once analized 1 and 2, for 3

$3^3+3^3<100$

$3^4+4^3>100$

and

$4^4+4^4>100$.

Comment: Is there any absolute method?

Comment: in this case I think the only way is by inspection, there is a limited number of cases to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force works.

Never be afraid to spend a little bit of time simply checking every possible value to see what works. Sometimes you'll quickly find the answer, or quickly recognize that a problem can be solved with a little more brute force (or possibly intelligent brute force)

Answer (score 0):

Let $E=a^b+b^a$

**Check**

For $ a = b = -1,-2,....$ or $ a , b \in (-∞,-1] $ the expression $E$ gets smaller and smaller.

While,

For $ a = b = +1,+2,....$ or $ a , b \in [1,+∞) $ the expression $E$ gets larger & larger.

So by hit & trail, we should notice,

$ At \ a=99 , b = 1 $ ,

$$ 99^1+1^{99}=100$$

$ At \ a=1 , b = 99 $ ,

$$ 1^{99}+99^1=100$$

Ordered Pairs:$ (1,99),(99,1)$

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that $a, b$ must have the same parity, i.e.

---

**$a,b$ - both even**, e.g. $a=2n$, $b=2m$ then 
$$(2n)^{2m}+(2m)^{2n}=2^{2}5^{2} \iff 4^mn^{2m}+4^nm^{2n}=4\cdot5^{2}$$
which leaves very few options for $m$ and $n$, e.g. assuming $n\leq m$ then $\color{red}{n \in \{0,1\}}$. Otherwise if $m\geq n \geq2$ then $100=4^mn^{2m}+4^nm^{2n}\geq 4^m2^{2m}+4^2m^{4}\geq4^22^4+4^22^4=512$-**contradiction**. Now:

- $n=0$ - doesn't make sense
- $n=1$ then $4^m1^{2m}+4m^{2}=4\cdot5^{2} \iff 4^{m-1}+m^{2}=5^{2}$, this is classical $4^2+3^2=5^2$ or $m=3$.

So, one solution is $\color{red}{a=2,b=6}$ (and vice-versa).

---

**$a,b$ - both odd**, e.g. $a=2n+1$, $b=2m+1$ then [(binomial expansion)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)
$$(2n+1)^{2m+1}+(2m+1)^{2n+1}=100 \iff \\
4N+(2m+1)2n+1+4M+(2n+1)2m+1=100 \iff \\
2N+(2m+1)n+2M+(2n+1)m=49 \iff \\
2N+2M+4nm=49-n-m$$
$m,n$ must have different parity since $49$ is odd.

- $n=2n_1+1$, $m=2m_1 \Rightarrow (4n_1+3)^{4m_1+1}+(4m_1+1)^{4n_1+3}=100$
- $n=2n_1$, $m=2m_1+1 \Rightarrow (4n_1+1)^{4m_1+3}+(4m_1+3)^{4n_1+1}=100$

both are identical, so let's look at
$$(4n_1+3)^{4m_1+1}+(4m_1+1)^{4n_1+3}=100$$
Obviously if $n_1\geq 1$ and $m_1\geq1$ we have
$$100 \geq 7^5+5^7$$
which is a **contradiction**, so we are left with

- $m_1=0$ and $n_1 \geq 0$ or $(4n_1+3)^1+1=100$ which has a solution.
- $n_1=0$ and $m_1 \geq 0$ or $3^{4m_1+1}+(4m_1+1)^3=100$ which has no solutions since for $m_1=1$ we have $100<368$ and $m_1=0$ doesn't make sense.

which is equivalent to either $\color{red}{b=1}$ (and $\color{red}{a=99}$) or $\color{red}{a=1}$ (and $\color{red}{b=99}$).

---

This way, we analysed all the possible cases, without brute forcing.